# How to read multiple documents in Firestore in a single request?

Tags: node.js, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

Assuming that I have the references of 4 documents, as follow:

```
users/user1/
preferences/user1
featureflags/user1
user_info/user1
```

how do I read all 4 documents in Firestore in a single request?

I tried with Promise.all as follow:

```
Promise.all([
    getUserInfo(user_id),
    getPreferences(user_id),
    getFeatureFlag(user_id),
    getUsers(user_id)
    ]
).then(function (ans) {
   //stuff
})
```

However, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Querying across multiple collections isn't possible, so you are doing the best job by putting them together in 1 promise and read them later on. You could choose an other [data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data?authuser=0).

Sending multiple request to the server [isn't as slow as you might think](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35932786/7715250). What you want is more SQL than NoSQL.